# Apps Script turn value between functions

Tags: google-apps-script

Hello everyone)) I have problem with moving value inside th function, please help me

First I have field "allValid" - has taken boolean value "true".

Next I did 3 checking breakpoints in script where this field must change boolean value on "false".
But whatever i do allValid always has "true". I cant understand what am I doing wrong.

```js
function ButtonClickAction(){  
  let allValid = true;
  var UserInfo = {};
  UserInfo.zLOGIN = document.getElementById("LOGIN").value;
  UserInfo.zSSCC = document.getElementById("SSCC").value;
  UserInfo.zPLACE = document.getElementById("PLACE").value;
                  
  var toValidate = {
    LOGIN: "LOGIN REQUIRED",
    SSCC: "SSCC REQUIRED",
    PLACE: "PLACE REQUIRED"
  }
  var idKeys = Object.keys(toValidate);

//first checking
  idKeys.forEach(function(id){
    isValid = checkIfValid(id,toValidate[id]);
    allValid = isValid;
  }); 

//second checking 
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onLOGIN).searchLogins(UserInfo);
    function onLOGIN(findLogin) {
      if (!findLogin) {
        alert("LOGIN NOT EXIST");
        allValid = false;
      }
    }

//thirdchecking 
    console.log(allValid);
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSSCC).searchSSCC(UserInfo);
    function onSSCC(findSSCC) {
      if (!findSSCC) {
        alert("SSCC NOT EXIST");
        allValid = false;
      }
    }

//finish result
      if (!allValid){
        alert("YOU HAVE NOTHING");
      } 
      else {
        addRecord(idElem);
      }
}

function checkIfValid(elId, message){

  var isValid = document.getElementById(elId).checkValidity();

  if(!isValid){
    alert(message);
    return false;
  } 
    return true;
}
```

At the end of the function "ButtonClickAction" I have "finish result", but it works wrong because allValid has always "true". Help!
(sorry for bad English, it's my non-native language, I try explain correctly)

... and some server code:

```js
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s8l-8N8dI-GGJi_mmYs2f_88VBcnzWfv3YHgk1HvIh0/edit?usp=sharing";
var sprSRCH = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
let sheetSRCHSSCC = sprSRCH.getSheetByName("PUTAWAY_TO");
let sheetTSD = sprSRCH.getSheetByName("ПРИВЯЗКА МЕСТ");
 
   

    function searchLogins(UserInfo){
        
        let sheetSRCHLGN = sprSRCH.getSheetByName("ЛОГИНЫ");
        let findingRLGN = sheetSRCHLGN.getRange("A:A").getValues();
        let valToFind = UserInfo.zLOGIN;
       
        for (let i = 0; i < findingRLGN.length; i++){
          if(findingRLGN[i].indexOf(valToFind)!==-1){
            return true;
          }
        };
        return false;
        
    }

    function searchSSCC(UserInfo){
        
        let findingRSSCC = sheetSRCHSSCC.getRange("M:M").getValues();
        let valToFind = UserInfo.zSSCС;
        
        for (let i = 0; i < findingRSSCC.length; i++){
          if(findingRSSCC[i].indexOf(valToFind)!==-1){
            return true;
            break;
          }
        };
        indx=2;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Do you also have any server code (Apps Script) along with this?

Comment: Yes, here it is, inserted) I completely forgot about this, excuse me...

Comment: The requirement for the questioner to create a [mcve] often leads the questioner to find the problem themselves by helping them to identify the problem by eliminating all of the code that is working properly.

Comment: I agree with you, but how can I create this example? Spreadsheets from server are in the Google job account. Code with problem I writed on top

Comment: What are you receiving when logging the `allValid`?